# which encryption algorithm does use in ask.fm?

Tags: security

Please help me in my project.
Determine which algorithm encryption data or detect anonymous in ask.fm?.
I tried to find anything about it.
I searched in ask.fm

Answer (score 0):

SSLLabs can help you determine which algorithm is used to encrypt data between the ask.fm servers and you:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ask.fm

You can use that too: https://tls.imirhil.fr/

Comment: please description how i use SSLLabs?

Comment: You go to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ write the domain name, if the domain is host by multiple ip you need click on the ip you want to check, then you wait the end of the test : https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ask.fm&s=66.235.122.114